# Angular 15 add browsernotification working on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: angular, browser, notifications

I am building a application and I want to display a notification when I have new data. This notification (browser):

[image]

I dont need any kind of backend service only want to know how I can build this only wth Angular 15.

After asking permission of a user I tried this:

```
new Notification("To do list", { body: 'Text'})
```

but nothing happends in Chrome it work fine firefox. Can someone help or explain what I need to do?

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I showed was correctly it had to do with secure policies that were added on the browser!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have notifications in your taskbar turned on?

See:

[image]

Comment: yes it is on also I see that I have permission. this is the code:

      Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if(permission === 'granted'){
          new Notification('To do list', { body: 'hello' });
        }
        
      });

Comment: Hmm - your code produces notifications in my Windows Taskbar Notification panel.  I assume that's where you're expecting them - not in the browser window, correct?

Comment: That is correct  I will try it on a other pc to check maybe its blocked somehow thx!.it should work on localhost correct?

Comment: Yes - should work just fine on localhost.  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: It works fine for me on firefox only for chrome it doesnt which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome v121.0.6167.85

Comment: It has to do with settings browser nothing wrong about code thx